# DATA INGESTION USING SQOOP

Tags: csv, hdfs, sqoop

I have to ingest a CSV file in HDFS using Sqoop.

The problem is that I am using a ',' (comma) as a separator, and my data also has a column with ','s. which is creating a problem parsing the data.

Can anyone suggest what should I do to solve the issue?

Can I use SQOOP or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the sqoop specific argument --fields-terminated-by to seperate the fields when importing the data to hdfs using sqoop.

If you are trying to import the csv file from local file system then in that case you can directly use hadoop fs -put command to put he files into hdfs.

Comment: Thanks ,  I am trying to import csv  file from my Mysql database to hdfs using sqoop